# NSDateformatter dateFromString AnyObject

Tags: ios, swift

I have an array of AnyObjects of NSDates and I am trying to convert to weekdays like (Mon, Tue, Wed..)

The Array looks like this when I print it to the console:

> [2014-12-03 22:16:26 +0000, 2014-12-05 22:16:26 +0000, 2014-12-11
>   22:16:26 +0000]

**This is my Code:**

```
var xAxisDates = [AnyObject]()


func dateformatter() {
    let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"

    let weekDayFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    weekDayFormatter.dateFormat = "EEE"

    println(xAxisDates)

    for i in xAxisDates{

        let date = formatter.dateFromString(i as String)
        println(weekDayFormatter.stringFromDate(date!))
    }
}
```

**The code crash at :**

> ```
>     let date = formatter.dateFromString(i as String)
> ```

I have been trying all day to figure out what I am doing wrong, and read practically every question on NSDateFormatter but to no avail.  I am down casting i as String because if I don´t I get error message AnyObject is not convertible to String. My feeling is that the type do not match up, but I am not sure, and I don´t know how to find out.  I have attached the error message as picture if that helps. If you can recommend a tutorial or book or something on how to understand what is wrong I would appreciate it, as I am trying to learn.

Any help would be much appreciated !

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `xAxisDates` array contains `NSDate` objects, therefore

```
let date = formatter.dateFromString(i as String)
```

does not make any sense, and `i as String` already crashes because `i` is an `NSDate`
and not a `String`.

You just need to convert the dates to a string:

```
for i in xAxisDates {
    println(weekDayFormatter.stringFromDate(i as NSDate))
}
```

or better check if the array elements actually are `NSDate` objects:

```
for i in xAxisDates {
    if let date = i as? NSDate {
        println(weekDayFormatter.stringFromDate(date))
    }
}
```

Comment: @leonardo-savio-dabus Thank you both for your help, it is much appreciated. When I saw both your solutions I see where I went wrong, wish I could see it before I was told it...!  I guess experience is what it is mostly about.  Thank you, so, so much

Answer (score 1):

```
extension NSDate {
    var weekdayName: String {
        let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "EEEE"
        return formatter.stringFromDate(self)
    }
}

let myArrayOfAnyObjects:[AnyObject] = [NSDate()]

myArrayOfAnyObjects.first!.weekdayName   // "Tuesday"
```